# Embedded videos from Vimeo in iOS app: “Sorry, because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played here”

Tags: ios, wordpress, video, ios9, vimeo

I have developed an iOS app that gets webviews from a Wordpress page. These Wordpress pages has embedded Vimeo videoes, which are hidden from Vimeo search and can only be seen and embedded on my domain.

I have a Wordpress plugin for embedding the Vimeo videos. Lately, in the app (not at the webpage/desktop view where the content also can be viewed), instead of showing the video I get the message “Sorry, because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played here”. When I go back to the menu, and then back to the video page (web view) a few seconds later, the video is shown and everything's working.

Is it something wrong with the plugin I use?(https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-responsive-video-embedder/)
Or maybe a cache delay?

Update: Can it have something to do with iOS9?

Update II:
I got an answer from Vimeo:

Hi there, Thank you for bringing this to our attention. We are currently aware of an issue where videos with domain-level embed privacy are not playable on Chrome and Safari for iOS 9.3, or Safari 9.1 for OSX due to a bug with Apple's WebKit browser engine.

We have confirmed that the next update to iOS, v9.3.2, will fix this issue. There is no ETA for the update, however, as Apple does not comment on the timing of their future releases. In the meantime, you should be able to work around this by temporarily disabling domain-level privacy for your videos.

Comment: Here's the relevant vimeo support thread: https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:281401

Answer (score 0):

Puffin works fine.

Download a browser app named PUFFIN from AppStore, it is able to run the videos which showed the privacy error in ios 9.3.